# How to solve this errorr CS1061?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace _2._1
{
class Narys
{
    public string Vardas { get; set; }
    public string Pavarde { get; set; }
    public double Pinigai { get; set; }
    public Narys()
    {
    }
    public Narys(string vardas, string pavarde, double pinigai)
    {
        Vardas = vardas;
        Pavarde = pavarde;
        Pinigai = pinigai;
    }
    List<Narys> DuomenuSkaitymas()
    {
        List<Narys> nariai = new List<Narys>();
        string[] eilutes = File.ReadAllLines(@"nariai.txt");
        foreach (string eilute in eilutes)
        {
            string[] duomenys = eilute.Split(' ');
            string vardas = duomenys[0];
            string pavarde = duomenys[1];
            double pinigai = double.Parse(duomenys[2]);
            Narys narys = new Narys(vardas, pavarde, pinigai);
            nariai.Add(narys);
        }
        return nariai;
    }
    void DuomenuIrasymas(List<Narys> nariai)
    {
        string[] eilutes = new string[nariai.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < nariai.Count; i++)
        {
            eilutes[i] = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", nariai[i].Vardas, nariai[i].Pavarde, nariai[i].Pinigai);
        }
        File.WriteAllLines(@"nariaiAts.txt", eilutes);
    }
    void DuomenuParodymas(List<Narys> nariai)
    {
        foreach (Narys narys in nariai)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Vardas: {0}\nPavarde: {1}\nPinigai: {2}", narys.Vardas, narys.Pavarde, narys.Pinigai);
        }
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        List<Narys> nariai = p.DuomenuSkaitymas();
        p.DuomenuIrasymas(nariai);
    }
}
}
```

[image: console]
[image: Error]
And why i'm getting those errors ?

I think it should work, but it isn't, so i guess you will be able to solve this sh*t. Also, i'm studying in university and i am doing this by example and it really should work. I think there should be enough info for you guys.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for textual information. Copy errors and log messages as text, and only provide images for context if necessary, but with a description of what they are showing. Not everyone can see images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look at your code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        List<Narys> nariai = p.DuomenuSkaitymas();
        p.DuomenuIrasymas(nariai);
    }
}
```

You are declaring the class `Program` that contains **only** a static method. Then you instantiate that class in variable `p`. Then you are trying to access some `DuomenuSkaitymas` method of it. But it contains **only** a static method. So how should this work?

You probably wanted to instantiate class `Narys` in `p` instead of `Program`.

Just a pro tip: never use identifier names in your local language, even if it looks more understandable at first. Your code might well end in the hands of others who don't understand your language. Believe me, you will choose better identifiers if you want others to understand your code - and that will be valuable to you too.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `Program` just contains the `main()` method, so the IDE informs you that `Program` does not contains `DuomenuSkaitymas` method.

That method (`DuomenuSkaitymas`) , is defined in the `Nary`'s class, so probably you need to modify you main method to

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Narys p = new Narys();
        List<Narys> nariai = p.DuomenuSkaitymas();
        p.DuomenuIrasymas(nariai);
    }
}
```

I didn't check what the program means itself just clarifying your CS1061, so if there is other problems try to look closely to the code and understand what it means. If any other issue non related to this CS1061 arises after that you could try to post a new question with your issues or ideas about it.